# SceneKit Group Animations

Tags: 3d, rotation, swift3, scenekit

I have a simple object in SceneKit and I'm trying to rotate the x and y axis (pitch and roll) at the same time.

```
let actionPitch = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4Make(1,0,0, pitch), duration: 0.1)
let actionRoll = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4Make(0,1,0, roll), duration: 0.1)
```

with

```
objectNode.runAction(SCNAction.group([actionRoll, actionPitch]))
```

But only the first action runs the second action in the group does not run.

Comment: It's because your two actions conflict with each, both have a different end rotation. Try using something else like `rotateByAngle`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try changing it